# Touch doesn't "stick" to view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios6

I need to have an image rotate (for example clockwise) in an iPad application. The image is held inside a view:

```
UIImageView *view1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startX+lineWidth, startY+lineHeight, lineWidth, lineHeight)];
view1.tag = 0;
view1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:0]];
```

In

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
```

I'm doing this:

```
CGPoint d1 = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
CGPoint d2 = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];               
CGFloat angle1 = atan2(d1.y, d1.x);
CGFloat angle2 = atan2(d2.y, d2.x);
subview.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(subview.transform, angle2-angle1);
```

The view is rotating, but it doesn't go smoothly together with the touch (or the cursor in my development environment.) Rather, it flotes a bit ahead of the touch.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` for this (see [Event Handling Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html) in the Apple doc)?

It will handle rotation using the standard rotation gesture (two fingers) and provide you and angle directly, and is easier to use.

But to answer your question directly, your problem is probably that you don't cumulate the angles. You apply a transform with `CGAffineTransformRotate` using `angle2-angle1` which is the difference in angle between the current touch and the previous touch. So each time you move your finger, you change the rotation of your `subview` by an angle that is only the difference between the previous point and the current one, not the starting point at the beginning of the touch and the current point. You should use the point retrieved in `touchesBegan:withEvent:` for `d2` instead of `previousLocationInView:`.

Comment: Thanks, AliSoftware, but both these don't work. I'm not using UIRotationGestureRecognizer because I need this to work for a one fingre touch, and when I'm using the point retrieved from touchesBegun for d2 the rotating image is completely out of touch with the cursor.

Comment: Well without further info I can't help much (for example you did log the points and angles your code computes each time to understand what's wrong, right?)

Comment: Yes, I did. I'll continue looking into it and when I find more info I'll report it here. Thanks again!